# How to declare Arrays in runtime in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I re-declare arrays in VB.NET at runtime?

**Example:**

When I run my program, I will have 100 arrays then I have my button that says "add", if I click it, a text box will appear and I can type there what ever I want to add in my arrays, also I can delete an existing array, but the problem is for example I want to delete an item, and that item is in array number 6, if I delete it, a new item will replace the array, how will I do it?

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using and can you provide any code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just to clarify... I think you mean to say that you have an (just one) array with 100 items. I don't think you mean 100 arrays.

Comment: @Richard Brightwell, Thats what I was wondering as well. I'm wondering if a List would more suit the needs then an array. But im not sure what hes looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To re-dimension an array use [`ReDim Preserve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)